# Core-Plot: how to change the pie-chart

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I am experimenting with Core Plot. I am trying to figuring out how to make the Pie Chart solid  and remove the space between AA and BB. Is there anyone nice that could give me a hint?

[image: nice]

Comment: Post some code - we can't tell what you are doing from just the photo. (makes sense, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either don't implement the `-radialOffsetForPieChart:recordIndex:` method in the datasource, or have it return 0.0 for every index.